# How to switch between favicons every couple of seconds using React Helmet?

Tags: reactjs, svg, favicon, react-helmet

The button is to change the alert useState from true to false.  Currently, the favicon is orange when true and gray when false.  I would like for the favicon to blink from orange to gray when the alert useState is set to true.  How would I go about this?

```
import orangeLogo from './src/images/orange-logo.svg'
import grayLogo from './src/images/gray-logo.svg'

const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(true)

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <link rel='icon' type='image' href={alert ? orangeLogo : grayLogo}/>
      </Helmet>
      <Layout {...props}><button onClick={() => setAlert(!alert)}>ALERT</button></Layout> 
    </>
  )
}
export { wrapPageElement }
```

My initial thought was to just make a gif, but apparently that hasn't been fruitful since firefox is the only browser that seems to support an animated favicon?

My thought right now is to someone use something like setInterval to switch between the SVGs, but I'm still fairly new to React and haven't been able to figure out how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval to toggle the state of alert in every 5 seconds like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setAlert(!alert);
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [alert]);
```